# Is linux suggest us use sysfs or udev?

Tags: embedded-linux

While we want to create a device file in file system, which one should we choose right now? Make a node in udev, which will show up in /dev or use sysfs which will show up in /sys.

I just think I can accomplish most of functions for a device through these two different ways. So it confused me a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch why don't we think the mechanism of kobject and sysfs is better?

Comment: What sort of device are you talking about? Be more specific!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i just think I can accomplish most of functions for a device through these two different ways. So it confused me a lot.

Comment: Please tell us more about the hardware device you want to write a driver for.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i feel sorry. But i just read some books and when i learnt these two thing i got this problem. And I will try to write a driver for a key buttom and wifi module.

Answer (score 0):

Use `udev` (and or define and publish some major & minor device numbers, like for `mknod`). See [makedev(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/makedev.3.html)

Application programs want to access physical devices in `/dev/`  (not in `/sys/`). Data to/from a device go usually thru `/dev/`  char or block devices. Metadata and configuration can go thru [sysfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs)

Read more about [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) and about [sysfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt). See also [device file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) wikipage.

You won't get very useful answers if you don't explain more concretely your issues... What exact kind of device are you thinking about? Very probably there exist already similar devices....

Publish very early (even in alpha stage, when it is not fully working) your device driver and software source code as [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) preferably as [GPLv2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html) (the license used by Linux kernel). Ask also on [kernelnewbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/). Work hard (perhaps more than a year) to get your driver incorporated in the official [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel).

You should be familiar with [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (in the application userspace world) before attempting to code a kernel driver. After that, read books and resources on Linux kernel driver programming and study the source code of existing drivers in the recent Linux [kernels](http://kernel.org/).

Comment: Thanks so much. And could you tell me when we can use /sys?